# Use Heroku with an existing GitHub repository

Tags: heroku, github

I have been creating a GitHub project. Now I'm planning on hosting it on Heroku. It looks like Heroku creates a new git repository and expects me to use it for my project. How can I point Heroku at my existing repository?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you still need your github repository.

```
git remote add heroku {heroku repository path}
```

will add another remote repository to your code,
then

```
git remote
```

will list all your remotes, probably

```
-- origin
-- heroku
```

and then

```
git push {remote name} {branch name}
```

will push to the appropriate remote:

```
git push heroku master
```

will start your deployment

```
git push origin
```

or probably just

```
git push
```

will push your changes just on github

Comment: I would clarify on what to do if the Heroku app already exists (as your answer assumes), or if you've yet to create it. In the latter case, `heroku create` will add the `heroku` remote for them.

Comment: Perfect explanation, thank you.